# How do I get arcade.draw_text to work in my python code for asteroids?

Tags: python-3.x, arcade

Here is that piece of code.

```
    'def remove_DeadObjects(self):'
            'for bullet in self.bullets:'
                'if not bullet.alive:'
                    'self.bullets.remove(bullet)'
                
            'for asteroid in self.asteroids:'
                'if not asteroid.alive:'
                    'self.asteroids.remove(asteroid)'
            'if not self.ship.alive:'
                'arcade.draw_text("Sorry, you got hit. Maybe try some spaceship training! See you soon!!", width = 300, height = 300,arcade.color.BLUE,)'
```

Answer (score 2):

You're passing wrong parameters to `draw_text` method. Here is the small example of how to use `draw_text` correctly:

```
import arcade

arcade.open_window(600, 400, 'Text example')
arcade.start_render()
arcade.draw_text(text='Sorry, you got hit. Maybe try some spaceship training!', start_x=20, start_y=200, color=arcade.color.RED, font_size=20)
arcade.finish_render()
arcade.run()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked for me. I appreciate your help.